# C# Extension Method to Calculate Position Between a Range

Tags: c#, extension-methods, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to write an extension method off a 'decimal' that calculates the value of a given number in relation to a given lower and upper range. I know that sounds a bit strange so here is a concrete example.

Lets say that there is a pay grade system in place at a particular place of work and the pay rate categories are as follows..

- Cat1 (0 - 20 hours) = $20/hour
- Cat2 (20 - 30 hours) = $22/hour
- Cat3 (30 - 40 hours) = $24/hour
- Cat4 (40 - 50 hours) = $26/hour
- Cat5 (50+ hours) = $28/hour

So...

- If a person worked 14 hours in a given week, they would earn (14 * 20)
- If a person worked 27 hours in a given week, they would earn (20 * 20) + (7 * 22)
- If a person worked 38 hours in a given week, they would earn (20 * 20) + (10 * 22) + (8 * 24)

and so on..

The extension method I have put together looks like this and its purpose is to return a single decimal that tells me if it falls into the given range or not. if it does it tells me how much by. if not it returns zero or the maximum value for that range. To be honest something about it doesnt seem right.

Can anyone verify that this is the correct logic and perhaps if there is anyway to optimise it?

```
public static decimal ValueBetween(this decimal m, decimal lower, decimal upper = decimal.MaxValue)
{
    return (m > lower)
        ? (m > upper)
            ? upper - lower
            : m - lower
        : 0m;
}
```

Example Usage with Expected Output

```
((decimal)14).ValueBetween(0, 20) = 14
((decimal)24).ValueBetween(0, 20) = 20
((decimal)24).ValueBetween(20, 30) = 4
((decimal)24).ValueBetween(30, 40) = 0
((decimal)150).ValueBetween(40) = 110
```

Thanks.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is to be more rigerous specifying your ranges. It looks like they should be half-open intervals, but as it stands (for example) the 30 hours figure appears in *two* of the rows. So if I work 30 hours, do I get $24/hour or $22/hour?

Comment: @MatthewWatson Hi, The ranges are specified by a 3rd party but the answer to your question is that they would receive (20*20)+(10*22).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you have is fine, except maybe you could make it a bit more readable:

```
public static decimal ValueBetween(this decimal m, decimal lower, decimal upper = decimal.MaxValue)
{
    if (m < lower) return 0M;
    if (m > upper) return upper - lower;
    return m - lower;
}
```